# Django forms.ModelForm slugfield db_index=True

Tags: python-3.x, django, slug

I have a slug field in my Model with `db_index=True`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
```

When a new record is added through my form, i want slug field to be filled with slugified text that I have coded in my model `save()` method. However, this never happens as I am stuck at form field level validation.

I have tried many options like `clean()`, `clean_field()` etc but all of them runs only after slug field has something entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must allow blank values to be entered on the form using `blank=True`. You will also generally want to use `unique=True` instead of `db_index=True` for a slug field:

```
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, blank=True, unique=True)
```

Note that `unique` implies `db_index`.

Comment: Thanks Selcuk it worked. I never paid attention to 'unique' that i also serves the same indexing purpose too... appreciated your help!